# How to read the querystring only in the first time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a hierarchical structure and when the user press on Add a child, I reopen the same page with [Add, ParentID] parameters.

The problem is, after pressing Add, a postback is made and the reading for the querystring is made again because the querystring is still the same and I catch & process it in the page_load.

**Note**: I can't use `IsPostBack` because the calling is from the same page, so it' always `true`.

Any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you only process the query string when the page has not been posted back, by using the [`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property of `Page`:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //Process query string
}
```

Comment: @Jack - If you called as a `Response.Redirect`, `IsPostBack` will be false.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not using `Response.Redirect`. I was using `PostBackURl` and it wasn't making a postback. Now, everything is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in the page load event or on you button click add this :

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
        'your code here
    End If
```

C#

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
//your code here
```

}

Using session

```
if (Session("ok") == 0) {
//some code
Session("ok") = 1;}
```

this will execute your query on the first load only !!!

Comment: This is also in VB.NET, where the question is tagged c#.

Comment: The calling is from the first page, so `IsPostBack` is true always

Comment: then use a session for this one

Answer (score 1):

```
If (!Page.isPostBack) {

//read your query string here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the page load event

add these code and see if it works

> if ((!IsPostBack)&&(!IsCallBack)) {
>   //some code! }

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  // Read the query string.
}
```